why i can't use float in in integrer
while counter < time :
w = d*u.copy()

for i in range(1, nodes -1):
    for j in np.arange(-1/2, 1/2):

        u[i] = ((w[j+1//2]/dx**2)*(u[i+1]-u[i]))

counter += dt
if f <= 0.5 :

IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
code program

As stated, floating point numbers are not valid, since the system cannot decide which element of a set you want for an expressions like array[1.5].

Maybe you meant to use w[(j+1)//2] ?

u is not defined in your snippet, please add relevant code or description how you are creating u

w[j+1//2]

This is almost certainly the problem.
Due to order of mathematical operations, the division 1//2 is performed first, which produces zero.
Then zero is added to j, which of course produces just j.
So this is equivalent to just w[j].
On the first iteration of the inner loop, j is 0.5, which causes the problem.  You can't index a sequence on a float value.
